# Securing django app on single SSL certificate using apache

Tags: django, apache

In the Django documentation I read that the app shouldn't be placed in the htdocs folder, thefore I have placed the folder in /home/django-apps/myapp

In my SSL virtual host I have the following:

```
Alias /media/ /home/django-apps/myapp/static/

WSGIScriptAlias / /home/django-apps/myapp/apache/django.wsgi

<Directory /home/django-apps>
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
 </Directory>
```

I have removed the various bit of the SSL certificate for security and brevity reasons.

Everything works fine, I just want to make sure that I haven't introduced a security hole with the Directory directive settings for django-apps.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks good to me. As far as I know theres is no problem, as long as directory permissions are set right. You also should place your .py files outside /htdocs or /httpdocs to prevent showing them by default apache configuration.

Hope this helps.